# Issue on Saving PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

At first : Sorry for my english, i'm French :p

I'm trying to generate a PDF Document with iTextSharp in a VB.NET web application, curently, i could generate it and save in my pc.

My worry is that when I open it with a pdf reader, and then closes the document, it asks me to save the changes. Without make any changes ! I just want to see my PDF, without this save ask.

This is how i generate and save my PDF :

```
'Déclaration des variables documents'
    Dim document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25)
    Dim output = New MemoryStream()
    Dim writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output)

    'Ouverture du document - Opening File '
    document.Open()

    'Ajout du contenu'  

    'Fermeture du document'
    document.Close()

    'Génération de l enregistrement'
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment;filename=Receipt-{0}.pdf", btn_test.Text))
    Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray())
```

Someone could help me to solve this ?

Comment: When a PDF document asks you to save it means the document is corrupt and the reader has made changes to fix the document. You need to advise what is corrupt.

Comment: *it means the document is corrupt and the reader has made changes* - It's not necessarily corrupt; pivotal is that the Reader has made changes. This also happens for **NeedsAppearances true** files. To find out more, therefore, please supply a sample file both as generated by your code (i.e. the content of `output.ToArray()`), and as saved by Adobe Reader.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want, the files I create before and after the save by the Reader ?

Comment: If that what you want : 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2tbw20piz7q1j3i/yMwE6MLU9s
You could find the both files here

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to populate your document ? (code that should be under 'Ajout du contenu')

Comment: dropbox.com/s/rozde67g2u618ap/code.vb You could find my code here, i didn't see what i'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you change the `Response` stream to something other than what ASP.Net is expecting you need to make sure to tell ASP.Net that you're done. After you calling `Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray())` make sure that you close the stream so that ASP.Net doesn't continue writing to it.

```
Response.End()
```

Also, you might want to throw a `Response.Clear()` at the top of the stream.

Comment: It Works ! Thanks a lot ! And my PDF be less heavy (286 Ko -> 276Ko)

Answer (score 1):

A substantial amount of random (?) trash appears after the actual end of your PDF. The PDF 1.7  specification allows *some* fluff:

> **3.4.4, “File Trailer”**
>
> 18. Acrobat viewers require only that the %%EOF marker appear somewhere within the last 1024 bytes of the file.

but checking the Before file, I found no less than 5,576 bytes of HTML after the last line

```
startxref
281974
%%EOF
```

Apparently, the modern Reader is even more fault-tolerant than Adobe recommends, but to prevent other readers running into problems, it urges you to save it as a correct PDF.

Proof: I removed everything after the last line `%%EOF` using a binary editor. The PDF opened correctly, and closed without warning.

---

As to where this HTML chunk came from, and how to prevent it, you'll have to go through the documentation of your toolchain.

Comment: So i have to remove everything after %%EOF ? How Can I do that ?

Comment: I used a binary editor. But the extra data is not really *random*; it appears there because of your current toolchain. I am sure this is not iTextSharp's doing; it must be something you are doing with the PDF after it has been created.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rozde67g2u618ap/code.vb
You could find my code here, i didn't see what i'm doing wrong :/